# Hide background from lower div on top div

Tags: html, css

I cant quite find a way to do this or even if its possible:

```
<body> has a background image
<div parent> has a background image
<div child></div>  has no background 
</div>
```

I want the child div to hide the parent div background but show the body background.

Comment: So basically that the parent has a hole in it? You could try it with a very large border, or set the child div to the site background, usually #fff/white

Comment: The child should be the hole in the parent div, like a window to the body background. A "mask" like effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/WM9Za/9/

You can use clip-path to cut out a rectangle, as shown in my fiddle.
You will be able to see the background image through that.

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(
    0 0,
    100px 0,
    100px 75px,
    75px 75px,
    75px 125px,
    125px 125px,
    125px 75px,
    100px 75px,
    100px 0,
    200px 0,
    200px 200px,
    0 200px,
    0 0
);
```

The upside to this method is that you don't have to add another background-image to the child and don't have to worry about positioning.

Comment: I voting this as the correct answer because of the no repeating the background and avoiding positioning issues factor.

Answer (score 1):

Solution from my comment with a border around the parent: http://jsfiddle.net/82k0767b/

css:

```
.parent{
    border: 20px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}
.child{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please note that I'm using images for background.

Comment: Then you might have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp But I've never tried it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fixed positioning on the background images, and I guess that is the effect you are looking for.

```
background: fixed;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4cr507a/

Comment: This is the effect that I was looking for, I need to see if I can apply it to my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Then you would have to add the same **background-color:** to the child as you have on the body.

Or make it dynamically with JS or jQuery, so it sets a div with id or class to have to same style background as the body. But the easiest way is to just set the same color on both.

Comment: The body background has an image which would be impossible to align with the child div. I cant use a solid color.

Answer (score 0):

Make this as concept: http://jsfiddle.net/8k4Lore4/1/

```
body {background: green;}    
.parent {background: red; width: 500px; height: 500px; padding: 50px;}    
.child {background: green; width: 500px; height: 400px;}
```

Just make the background for body and child with the same image background that you will use.

Hope this will help you :)